# What is the best way to handle basic document file downloads in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The past few dayys I have been making my portfolio website and learning React at the same time and I would like to have my resume available for download. In the past, I have just used:

```
<a href="/my/file/location/file.txt" download>Click to download!</a>
```

bu for whatever reason the file can never be found. I assume this has to do with how the file system is being navigated. I had a similar issue trying to display images, but I was just able to import them. Is there a particular way I should be referencing the file location or is it something else altogether?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the file in the public folder. Build the project runing npm run build. Make sur the file is in the build folder. The path should be /filename.extension

Comment: Worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to help the browser locate the file by providing a valid URL. Here's a basic guide to URLs: http://webreference.com/html/tutorial2/index-2.html

The href value you've previously been using is called a relative URL, and as the name suggests it's relative to the URL of the page that the link is included on. A good first step would be to find an absolute URL that works correctly, and then look at shortening it to a relative URL.